# How to change cell background color based on its value to certain columns only

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, rows

I am using this template below to change the colour of certain cells when they meet a CASE condition. The Function applies itself to all rows in the dynamic row table. I have tried to modify this Function to restrict the Cell color change to ONLY columns 4, 5 and 6. My table has 9 columns altogether. I would very much appreciate any assistance.

```
function formatCells(table){
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
        cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td'),
        colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
    for (var c = 0, len = cells.length; c < len; c++){
        if (cells[c].cellIndex > 0){
            switch (parseInt((cells[c].textContent || cells[c].innerText), 10)){
                case 1:
                    cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colors[1];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cells[c].style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

formatCells(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following modified if statement will restrict the colour change to the 4th, 5th and 6th columns:

`if ([3,4,5].indexOf(cells[c].cellIndex) >= 0)`

`[3,4,5]` gives the 4th, 5th and 6th columns (accounting for JavaScript's zero based array numbering

`indexOf() >= 0` will be true if the argument is in the array or string

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan.. This is a very elegant solution. It works perfectly.  very much appreciated..